# Is it a correct scenario of Polymophism in C++?

Tags: c++, static-polymorphism

I am in a weird confusion after these many years. I know about the Runtime Polymorphism issues, virtual functions and many of those stuffs but could not be sure about the code sample below:

```
    class A{
    public:
        void f(){
            cout<<"I m called from A"<<endl;
        }
    };

    class B : public A{
    public:
        void f(){
            cout<<"I m called from B"<<endl;
        }
    };

    int main(void){
        B* b1 = new B();    
        A* a1 = b1; //Object reference of class B is assigned to a pointer of class A

        b1->f(); //Output is "I m called from B"
        a1->f(); //Output is "I m called from A"

        return 0;
    }
```

Considering the **C++** scenario above my questions are:

1. **Can I call this scenario as polymorphism?**
2. **If yes then can I refer this as static/compile-time polymorphism?**
3. **If no then should I assume that this is an incorrect implementation and virtual must be used?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing a `virtual` for the declaration of `A::f()`

Comment: This isn't 'static polymorphism'. This is 'no polymorphism'.

Comment: actually my point was, here the same object is showing different behavior if they are accessed with different pointer. can you please be more specific about my 3rd question? cubic

Comment: There are many different thing wrapped up the in term "polymorphism".
Subclassing *is* a form of polymorphism.

Comment: Perhaps re-tag with language lawyer and ask if this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply. Now my question is if it is incorrect implementation then why this is allowed in C++? to facilitate the static polymorphism I guess. Am I right? @πάντα-ῥεῖ

Comment: @ShovraDas There are still other use cases for inheritance, without realizing virtual polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. **Can I call this scenario as polymorphism?**

No.

> 2. **If yes then can I refer this as static/compile-time polymorphism?**

No. See below.

> 3. **If no then should I assume that this is an incorrect implementation and virtual must be used?**

Yes, using `virtual void f();` should fix your sample . You can get around using `virtual` with static polymorphism with something like this:

```
    template<typename Derived>
    class A{
    public:
        void f(){
            static_cast<Derived*>(this)->fImpl();
        }
        void fImpl() {
            cout<<"I m called from A"<<endl;
        }
    };

    class B : public A<B> {
    public:
        void fImpl(){
            cout<<"I m called from B"<<endl;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Static polymorphism is arguably unnecessary here. Indeed the application of `virtual` is enough to make it work.

Comment: @0x499602D2 OP asked for it.

Comment: No he didn't. He's asking if his original program is an example of static polymorphism. Speaking of which your answer should differentiate static and runtime ploymorphism: *"If no then should I assume that this is an incorrect implementation and virtual must be used?"* The answer is yes OR that he use static polymorphism (your example).